# Помогите найти ошибку в media-запросах

Tags: css, media-queries

Добрый день!
Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в media-запросах
Ошибка происходит в media-запросах для IPad и IPad Pro
А именно, стили, которые должны быть применены к IPad Pro в портретной ориентации

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
and (orientation: portrait)
```

Применяются к IPad в горизонтальной ориентации

`@media only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 768px) 
 and (max-device-width : 1024px)
 and (orientation : landscape)`

Подскажите, как это исправить?

Спасибо!

Comment: Можете показать пример страницы, где такое происходит?

Comment: А что если добавить  (значения взяты наобум, подставьте соответствующие высоты экрана)
 `and (min-device-height : 568px) 
 and (max-device-height : 824px)`

Comment: Мало кода, чтобы понять в чем может быть проблема, создайте - [mcve]